# How to install the accounting module for free

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I installed odoo 14 on my local machine, but I cannot install the accounting module. When I search for available applications, I found the accounting module, but with the update button and not install. Once I click on update I am redirected to buy a subscription on the odoo site. If the button update so it is already installed but I cannot find it in the list of applications already installed.

With the developer mode I managed to display the accounting module which is hidden in the invoicing module, but if it's a non-developer who uses the Information System how can we do it?

Comment: Accounting module will display as invoicing app.

Comment: @Neural yes I know but doesnt show if we dont install the accounting application

Comment: You already check group for your application menu? I faced some issue like this because my menu item is in technical group. You can try to remove in setting>techinal>menu items>

Comment: If you have still problem and you have some issues in your installation.You can follow this script and easily can install https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript

Answer (score 0):

Accounting module is only for Enterprise edition:
https://www.cybrosys.com/odoo/compare-odoo-community-vs-enterprise/

But you can try this module:
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/om_account_accountant

How to install custom module:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJyPx5u6sd0

Also remember you will need proper localisation for your country:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/applications/finance/accounting/fiscal_localizations/overview/fiscal_localization_packages.html

List of supported countries:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/applications/finance/accounting/fiscal_localizations/overview/localizations_list.html